# Ternary Operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently started learning Ternary Operator. However I am stuck in this specific one. In JavaScript language, I want to check if a student is a member of the library, if the student is, it has to print "You are a member!" if not, it has to print "Not found!". To check, we can use the student id for the validation of the library membership.

Comment: Please, provide some code.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, so I ended up doing some rough coding. 
var totalstudents = 10, stdid;  
var id = window.prompt("Enter your student id: ");
for (stdid=1; stdid<=totalstudents; stdid++){
{id === stdid ? "You are a member of the library" : "id NOT FOUND!!!"}
}

Comment: If you want to use the ternary operator for this an example would be `const msg = library.hasMember(student) ? "You are a member!" : "Not found!"` then print the message. `console.log(msg)`. However in this scenario a normal if-statement is might be a better fiit.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier for me to tailor my answer to your need if I had some code to work with. But basically, you can use something as simple as:

`studentIsMember ? 'You are a member' : 'Not found!'`

This will print `'You are a member'` if `studentIsMember` is true and `'Not Found'` if false.

If you need to lookup students in a members list using their id, you can have something like:

`members.includes(student.id) ? 'You are a member' : 'Not found!'`

this will look into the `members` array which holds an array of all members IDs and see if the specific student id is in that array.

Lastly, if you have to do more operations to validate a student's membership status, you can write a function that does the operations and returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the student is a member or not, and then use the ternary operator like this:

`studentIsMember(student.id) ? 'You are a member' : 'Not found!'`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used this and it displays id not found even though the id is included in the ids.
`const ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];`
`var id = window.prompt("Enter your student id: ");`
`{id.includes(ids) ? console.log("You are a member of the library") : console.log("id NOT FOUND!!!")}`

Comment: `window.prompt()` returns a string. Also, make sure you use `ids.includes(id)`. The syntax is basically: `[array].includes([element])`.

To fix your issue, you will have to check the user input and make sure you turn it into a number using `Number()`.